# Extracting individual digits from a long in C

Tags: c

I'm doing a homework assignment for my course in C (first programming course). 
Part of the assignment is to write code so that a user inputs a number up to 9 digits long, and the program needs to determine whether this number is "increasing"/"truly increasing"/"decreasing"/"truly decreasing"/"increasing and decreasing"/"truly decreasing and truly increasing"/"not decreasing and not increasing". (7 options in total)

Since this is our first assignment we're not allowed to use anything besides what was taught in class:

do-while, for, while loops, else-if, if, 
break,continue
scanf, printf ,modulo, and the basic operators

(We can't use any library besides for stdio.h)

That's it. I can't use arrays or `getchar` or any of that stuff. The only function I can use to receive input from the user is `scanf`.

So far I've already written the algorithm with a flowchart and everything, but I need to separate the user's input into it's distinct digits.

For example, if the user inputs "1234..." i want to save 1 in a, 2 in b, and so on, and then make comparisons between all the digits to determine for example whether they are all equal (increasing and decreasing) or whether a > b >c ... (decreasing) and so on.

I know how to separate each digit by using the % and / operator, but I can't figure out how to "save" these values in a variable that I can later use for the comparisons.

This is what I have so far:

```
printf("Enter a positive number : ");

do {
    scanf ("%ld", &number);
    if (number < 0) {
        printf ("invalid input...enter a positive integer: ");
        continue;
    }
    else break;
} while (1);

while (number < 0) {
    a = number % 10;
    number = number - a;
    number = number / 10;
    b = a;
}
```

Comment: Wait, they want you to split a number up into "up to 9" digits, but they won't let you use an array? Thats... that's just cruel!

Comment: that's only the first part...another part is related to the goldbach theory, user inputs any number up to 9 digits and computer outputs the first primes that add up to that number. same limitations for that as well

Comment: I do not understand your concept of increasing vs. truly increasing.  And what is "increasing and decreasing" vs. "truly decreasing and truly increasing".  Please clarify how your code is supposed to classify the input.

Comment: truly decreasing means that every digit is greater than the preceding digit, and "decreasing" means that every digit is great/equal than the preceding digit.

Comment: @nofe Then how can something be both truly increasing and truly decreasing?

Comment: @AaronDufour I see that my homework has succeeded in challening you, that makes me feel better about myself. I've concluded from the .exe the professor provided us to play with (the solution program) that a single digit is both truly decreasing and truly increasing. A number whose digits are all equal is "decreasing and increasing"

Comment: @nofe Since your problem only requires comparing consecutive digits, the "no arrays" requirement may have been your professor's way of pushing you in the direction of not storing all of the digits.  See my answer for what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not scan them as characters (string)? Then you can access them via an array offset, by subtracting the offset of 48 from the ASCII character code. You can verify that the character is a digit using `isdigit` from ctype.h.

---

**EDIT**

Because of the incredibly absent-minded limitations that your professor put in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int number;
  printf("Enter a positive number: ");

  do
  {
    scanf ("%ld", &number);
    if (number < 0)
    {
      printf ("invalid input...enter a positive integer: ");
      continue;
    }
    else break;
  } while (1);

  int a = -1;
  int b = -1;
  int c = -1;
  int d = -1;
  int e = -1;
  int f = -1;
  int g = -1;
  int h = -1;
  int i = -1;

  while (number > 0)
  {
    if (a < 0) a = number % 10;
    else if (b < 0) b = number % 10;
    else if (c < 0) c = number % 10;
    else if (d < 0) d = number % 10;
    else if (e < 0) e = number % 10;
    else if (f < 0) f = number % 10;
    else if (g < 0) g = number % 10;
    else if (h < 0) h = number % 10;
    else if (i < 0) i = number % 10;

    number /= 10;
  }

  /* Printing for verification. */

  printf("%i", a);
  printf("%i", b);
  printf("%i", c);
  printf("%i", d);
  printf("%i", e);
  printf("%i", f);
  printf("%i", g);
  printf("%i", h);
  printf("%i", i);

  return 0;
}
```

The valid numbers at the end will be positive, so those are the ones you validate to meet your different conditions.

Comment: i listed the limitations I have for this assignment above...asking "why not just do this" or that is irrelevant. You might as well ask me why I'm even learning C (why not Java? C++?). I am because that's what my university demands of me

Comment: If you can scan integers, you can scan characters. An array offset is basically addition, which meets the limitation of basic operators.

Comment: I can scan characters, you're right. Can you explain how to do an array offset without using an array (don't know what an array is) as for isdigit I can't use that or any other library besides stdio.h but that's ok because i don't need to verify that the characters are indeed digits, the user only inputs whole numbers.

Comment: You would need to have knowledge of pointers, which I doubt you do at this stage. A string in C is actually a pointer to an array of characters terminated by a null byte. This may be too advanced for what your teacher will accept.

Comment: yes..that's totally unfamiliar and I can only use what I saw in the 3 lectures we had so far.

Comment: hey im trying to test your code in Visual studio and this keeps popping up during the build:   Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' c:\users\chanoch\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\workspace\workspace\practice3.c 19 1 workspace

Comment: I rewrote the declaration of the variables and it worked. Thanks! (I changed it to this and put it in the beginning  int number,a=-1,b=-1,c=-1,d=-1,e=-1,f=-1,g=-1,h=-1,i=-1; )

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need to compare consecutive digits, there is an elegant way to do this without arrays:

```
int decreasing = 2;
int increasing = 2;

while(number > 9)
{
  int a = number % 10;
  int b = (number / 10) % 10;

  if(a == b)
  {
    decreasing = min(1, decreasing);
    increasing = min(1, increasing);
  }
  else if(a > b)
    decreasing = 0;
  else if(a < b)
    increasing = 0;

  number /= 10;
}
```

Here, we walk through the number (by dividing by `10`) until only one digit remains.  We store info about the number up to this point in `decreasing` and `increasing` - a `2` means truly increasing/decreasing, a `1` means increasing/decreasing, and a `0` means not increasing/decreasing.

At each step, `a` is the ones digit and `b` is the tens.  Then, we change `increasing` and `decreasing` based on a comparison between `a` and `b`.

At the end, it should be easy to turn the values of `increasing` and `decreasing` into the final answer you want.

Note: The function `min` returns the smaller of its 2 arguments.  You should be able to write your own, or replace those lines with `if` statements or conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose you have this number 23654

```
23654 % 10000 = 2 and 3654
3654 % 1000 = 3 and 654
654 % 100 = 6 and 54
54 % 10 = 5 and 4
4
```

This way you can get all the digits. Of course, you have to know if the number is greater than 10000, 1000, 100 or 10, in order to know the first divisor.

Play with sizeof to get the size of the integer, in order to avoid a huge if...else statement

**EDIT:**

Let us see

```
if (number>0) {
    // Well, whe have the first and only digit
} else if (number>10) {
    int first_digit = number/10;
    int second_digit = number % 10;
} else if (number>100) {
    int first_digit = number/100;
    int second_digit = (number % 100)/10;
    int third_digit = (number % 100) % 10;
} ...
```

and so on, I suppose

Comment: I need to put this into a loop because I need to handle up to 9 digits. Also, I want to "save" those digits somewhere or assign them to variables so that I can use them for my comparisons

Answer (score 1):

It's stupid to ask you to do loops without arrays --- but that's your teacher's fault, not yours.

That being said, I would do something like this:

```
char c;
while (1) {
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c == '\n')    /* encountered newline (end of input) */
        break;
    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        break;        /* do something to handle bad characters? */
    c -= '0';
    /*
     * At this point you've got 0 <= c < 9. This is
     * where you do your homework :)
     */
}
```

The trick here is that when you type numbers into a program, you send the buffer all at once, not one character at a time. That means the first scanf will block until the entire string (i.e. "123823" or whatever) arrives all at once, along with the newline character ( '\n' ). Then this loop parses that string at its leisure.

**Edit** For testing the increasing/decreasing-ness of the digits, you may think you need to store the entire string, but that's not true. Just define some additional variables to remember the important information, such as:

```
int largest_digit_ive_seen, smallest_digit_ive_seen, strict_increasing_thus_far;
```

etc. etc.

Comment: thanks, I actually already knew how to verify input validity but you're convincing me to consider using char again. what does parse mean?

Comment: "Parse" means analyze (roughly). The `char` data type is like `int` but smaller: It can only handle numbers in the range of -128 to 127 (but that's fine for a single digit which can only be 0-9 anyway). The reason I use `char` is because I want to use `%c` which only reads exactly one digit. But `scanf` requires you to use a `char` to use `%c`. Other than that, it might as well be `int` instead of `char` --- it's just storing a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
// u_i is the user input, My homework asked me to extract a long long, however, this should also be effective for a long.

int digits = 0;
long long d_base = 1;
int d_arr[20];
while (u_i / d_base > 0)
{
    d_arr[digits] = (u_i - u_i / (d_base * 10) * (d_base * 10)) / d_base;
    u_i -= d_arr[digits] * d_base;
    d_base *= 10;
    digits++;
}
```

EDIT: the extracted individual digit now lives in the int array d_arr. I'm not good at C, so I think the array declaration can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in plain C :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long alePow (unsigned long int x, unsigned long int y);

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
   int enter_num, temp_num, sum = 0;
   int divisor, digit, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter number\n");
    scanf("%d", &enter_num);

   temp_num = enter_num;

   // Counting the number of digits in the entered integer
   while (temp_num != 0)
   {
       temp_num = temp_num/10;
       count++;
   }

   temp_num = enter_num;

   // Extracting the digits
   printf("Individual digits in the entered number are ");
   do
   {
       divisor = (int)(alePow(10.0, --count));
       digit = temp_num / divisor;
       temp_num = temp_num % divisor;

       printf(" %d",digit);
       sum = sum + digit;
   }
   while(count != 0);

   printf("\nSum of the digits is = %d\n",sum);

   return 0;
}


unsigned long alePow(unsigned long int x, unsigned long int y) {

    if (x==0) { return 0; } 
    if (y==0||x==1) { return 1; } 
    if (y==1) { return x; }
    return alePow(x*x, y/2) * ((y%2==0) ? 1 : x);
}
```

Comment: thanks, some of this is useful. I don't want to sum the digits though I want to compare between them. Also I can't use math.h

Comment: Updated without using math.h, take a look at alePow function ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *loop-unrolling*.

```
int a=-1, b=-1, c=-1, d=-1, e=1, f=-1, g=-1, h=-1, i=-1; // for holding 9 digits
int count = 0; //for number of digits in the given number


if(number>0) {
i=number%10;
number/=10;
count++;
}

if(number>0) {
h=number%10;
number/=10;
count++;
}

if(number>0) {
g=number%10;
number/=10;
count++;
}
....
....
/* All the way down to the storing variable a */
```

Now, you know the number of digits (variable count) and they are stored in which of the variables. Now you have all digits and you can check their "decreasing", "increasing" etc with lots of if's !

I can't really think of a better soltion given all your conditions.

Comment: OK, I thought I could cut corners with a big loop that does it all but according to what you're saying I'll have to do it this way. I had this already myself I was just hoping for a shortcut. thanks

Comment: Because your conditions make it really tough to write a better solution for this :)

Comment: @nofe you can use a loop and you almost certainly should use a loop here! `int a, b, c, d...` is the same as `int digits[9]`, so if you have an array then you can easily loop through all of the digits.

Comment: @Lirik: But he can't use arrays.

Comment: @EvanMulawski doh! Well, that's a bummer! Scrap my comments then :).