# C recursion - increase each digit of a number by 1 except digit number 9 which will be 0

Tags: c, function, recursion, numbers, digits

i already managed to create a function which returns every number's digit(0-8) by 1.

example : 
input : 3
output: 4

input : 345
output: 456

**But i have a problem finding a solution for digit number 9 which need to return 0 .**

example: 
input : 9
output: 0

input : 945
output: 56

input : 99
output: 0

input : 19 
output: 20

**NOTE: 
Do not specifically check if the digit is 9**

my code:

```js
int new_num(int num){
    int dig = num%10;
    num = num/10;

    if( num==0 ){
        return dig+1;
    }
    int res = new_num(num);
    dig +=1;
    res *=10;
    res +=dig;
    return res;   
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting individual digits from a long in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045158/extracting-individual-digits-from-a-long-in-c)

Comment: no. 
i dont need to check if the number is increasing etc..
also , i haven't seen any solutions that can help me.

Comment: What should the output be for 19?

Comment: output should be 2

Comment: And for 19293 it should be 234? You should clarify your question a bit.

Comment: shouldn't 19 output 20?

Comment: output should be 20? 1+1=2; 9+1=0 --> 2 0

Comment: *"Do not specifically check if the digit is 9"* - Why, and what does it really mean? I can think of several ways that does not check this but sort of does, depending on who you ask.

Comment: Hint: `(9 + 1) % 10` is zero

Comment: SORRY . i was mistaken . output of 19 should be 20 . 
only if digit number 9 appear in the left side of the number we need to ignore it.

about why i cant check number 9 specifically is because its a school assignment and that was the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int new_num( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    return ( n % Base + 1 ) % Base +
           ( n / Base == 0 ? 0
                             : Base * new_num( n / Base ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%d -> %d\n", 99, new_num( 99 ) );
    printf( "%d -> %d\n", 945, new_num( 945 ) );
    printf( "%d -> %d\n", 19, new_num( 19 ) );
    printf( "%d -> %d\n", 123456789, new_num( 123456789 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
99 -> 0
945 -> 56
19 -> 20
123456789 -> 234567890
```